# Matrix Multiplication in Python Changes the Result Dimension

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have 1X2 matrix, `Mu_I.transpose()`, and a 2x2 matrix, `Covariance_I_Inverse`.

The result of multiplication should be a 1x2 matrix, but my output is a 2x2 matrix.

Why? How can I get a 1x2 Matrix?

```
>>> Mu_I.transpose()
[[ 10.02010924   9.99184818]]

>>> Mu_I.transpose().shape
(1, 2)

>>> Covariance_I_Inverse
[[ 0.72006911  0.        ],
 [ 0.          0.77689697]]

>>> Covariance_I_Inverse.shape
(2, 2)

>>> (Mu_I.transpose()*Covariance_I_Inverse)
[[ 7.21517113  0.        ],
 [ 0.          7.76263658]]

>>> (Mu_I.transpose()*Covariance_I_Inverse).shape
(2, 2)
```

Comment: thanks you all, that was exactly the case, so how can I find that I'm working with array or matrix, cuz I'm workin with framework that I've just installed and I don't know the codes

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing those variables are `numpy.array`, but not `numpy.matrix`. For `numpy.array`, `*` is defined as element-wise multiplication. In that case use `numpy.dot()`. That will give you matrix multiplication.

Or simply use `numpy.matrix` and `* operator` will be matrix multiplication.

Comment: or better, stick with arrays and use np.dot. It's less confusing if arrays and matrices are not mixed in the same code. repr(y) or type(y) shows the type, matrix or array or any other subclass of array.